# Removing parent div containing many divs and spans and sections in it using javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a comment div. so in this div, i have some other divs and spans to show edit and delete buttons, comment text, time, user name, profile pic and footer section for like or dislike.

Here is full code

```
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($rest)) {
<div class="container1" id="container1">
 <div class="div-image">
   <img src="images.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="div-right">
   <div class="div-right-top">
     <div class="div-user-name">
       <span class="text-user-name">
          UserName
       </span>
     </div>
     <div class="div-time">
       <span class="time-text">
         comment-time 
       </span>
     </div>
     <?php if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) { ?>
     <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="commentingid" value="FETCHVALUE" />
     <div class="div-myoptions">
       <span class="time-text div-option-div">
      <?php if($userid !== $loggedid) { ?>
        <button class="mycomoptions" type="submit" name="favorite">Fav</button> 
        <button class="mycomoptions" type="submit" name="flag">Report</button>
     </form>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <button class="edit" type="button">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete" data-emp-id="<?php echo $comentid ?>">X</button>
      <?php } ?>
       </span>
     </div>
      <?php } ?>
   </div>
   <div class="div-right-mid comment-text">

      <?php echo $fetch['usercom'] ?>  

   </div>
        <section class="right-bottom small">
                <div class="div-like">
                    <span class="text-bottom">
                        Up 
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="div-dislike">
                    <span class="text-bottom">
                        Down 
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="div-reply">
                    <span class="text-bottom">
                        reply 
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div id="editcoment" class="collapse">
                <p>
                <form action="" method="post" name="updatecom" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
                <input type="text" />
                <button type="submit" name="updatecom">Submit</button></p</form>
               </p>
  </div>
  </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

All I want to do is to delete the container1 div when i click on Delete button
Delete button is working, comment is deleted from database but its not been deleted from the page right after confirmation dialogue done with ajax. so when i refresh the page, comment is deleted. but why is it not working with ajax. is it just because i have spans and sections in the parent div?

here its javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.mycomoptions').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var delete = $(this).attr('data-emp-id');
    var container1 = $(this).parent("#container1 div");
    bootbox.dialog({
        message: "Delete Comment??",
        title: "Sure Delete?",
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "No",
                className: "btn",
                callback: function() {
                    $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                }
            },
            danger: {
                label: "Yes",
                className: "btn-danger",
                callback: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>',
                    data: 'delete='+delete
                })
               .done(function(){
                   container1.remove();
                })
            }
        }
    }
});
});
});
```

When i use simple divs then it works fine, but with this template of divs, its not removing container div on confirming Yes from confirmation dialogue. Need Help to understand how to make container variable to select parent div including all internal divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `var container1 = $(this).parent("#container1 div");` but you have no element with an `id` of `container1`.  Do you mean to be using `$(this).parent(".container1 div")`?

Comment: i forgot to mention it in question. i edited the question, the parent div has this id but not working

Comment: OK, great.  Next question: why are you selecting`$(this).parent("#container1 div")` rather than just `$(this).parent("#container1")`?

Comment: because container1 contains other divs in it, also, i have tried it    `$(this).parent("#container1")` but it did not work

Comment: I'm a bit confused, which div do you want deleted?

Comment: I want to delete full comment div which is the main container div

Comment: I still don't think I follow what you want removed.  Perhaps try the `.parents("#container1 div")` selector.

Comment: Sir, actually this container1 div is the div being created with every comment due to while loop, which is fetching comments from the databse. so if in database, there are total 5 comments, it means there are total 5 container1 divs including all internal div set. So, when i delete a comment, i want the whole div with all its material to be removed immediately with whole set/bunch of divs in container1. obviously when container1 div will be removed. everything in it will be disappeard at once

Comment: Ah, I see!  In that case, you're creating `div` elements with redundant IDs, which you can't do.  I would recommend using the class selector.

Comment: I tried     `.parents("#container1 div")` it. its removing only the comment but the div is still there. is not there any way to delete the grand-grand parent div with all its internal stuff

Comment: Can you try just using `.parents("#container1")`?  Still, I would strongly recommend not creating `div` elements with redundant ids.  You could achieve the same with `.parents(".container1")`.

Comment: Its really a great idea, its working on test page. but on the index page its still not working. i dnt know whats wrong with it on the main index page :(